# Arduino fails with Serial.println

Tags: arduino

I've got an Arduino which works with the following basic example for blinking:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                     // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                     // wait for a second
}
```

But if I add `Serial.println` it doesn't blink and doesn't output anything to the Serial moniter:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("Loop"); 
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                     // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                     // wait for a second
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried other baud rates?  (ie try 9600)

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong you may have a bad chip, or your baud rate too high, try 9600

Also can you give me details on your chip, some chips don't have serial.
If you're using the same chip as the leonardo you may need this:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) {} //Wait for serial port to connect
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the baud rate in `Serial.begin(115200)` the receiving terminal should have the same baud rate or you will see nothing there.